# How do I run a list of "on-hold" email addresses?

Tags: civimail

I want to run a current list of emails that are "on Hold" in our system.  How do I do this?

Comment: did the advanced search work for you? could you accept the answer so the question is closed and others know it works?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "advanced search", there is an option to select the emails that are on hold

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to dredge this question up because I just discovered something for myself here:

(I am currently using civiCRM 4.6.4)

**Advanced Search:** The email On Hold search option brings up "On Hold = 1", which will bring up all users with 'On Hold Bounce'. This does not seem to bring up users with 'On Hold Opt Out'.

**Search Builder:** It turns out that the value for 'On Hold User Opt Out' seems to be '2'. The only ways I have found to bring this up are in Search Builder either by searching "On Hold != 0" or "On Hold > 0" if you want to bring up all on hold contacts at once.

An interesting note is that if I search 'On Hold = 2' I get an error message "please enter a valid value"... so to bring up contacts with 'on hold user opt' out I need to search for 'On Hold > 1'.